# texture paint going wrong

Tags: texture-painting

everytime I try to use texture paint, it uses another material to paint it, for example, here it uses an earlier texture[image]

Comment: Check out my scrapbook on texture painting, bumps, etc. 88 pages. If using phone tablet, be careful with your fingers on screen, as pages contain links. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10l5N7JILfF59AvlwjUqP76t044ecXb-MUj1qm9W-IUU/mobilepresent?slide=id.g60ca14e196ecde6_0

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after this question I fixed it by clicking the texture category and clicking on the X